Convergence issue for ions with GPAW
How best to do relaxation on charged molecules (plus and minus one electron) from the initial geometry of the relaxed neutral system? Two examples are CCOCCOCC(F)F and CCS(=O)(=O)C=C, where the former converges for +-1 in charge and the latter fails. Parameters of the calculator are identical:
mol.center(vacuum = 10)
calc = GPAW(
    mode = "fd", 
    basis = "dzp",
    xc = "PBE",
    h = 0.13,
    charge = 1       # -1
)
opt = QuasiNewton()
opt.run(fmax=0.02)

I have attempted to increase the max iterations to 500 and changed the eigensolver to RMM-DIIS to no avail. Originally, the system was PF6 - solvent - Na. The PF6 and Na converges just fine at their own, but some of the solvent molecules fails to converge.
Do you have any tips and tricks for converging charged systems? I need an automatic method as I have 126 solvent molecules.
regards,
Jakob.

Would it help to allow for partial occupancies? What are potential drawbacks of this? I'll try..

+1 but ideally you would stick to just one question regardless of how related your questions are (your comment adds two more questions).
